# Azure App deployment Frustrating - Url redirects me to Tutorial

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2017

I have Created a simple app in visual studio 2017,

I have also created a free Azure account to test a deployment. I have Followed all the steps Microsoft has advised to do.  Very simple!!!

Once I deploy via Visual Studio using my account, My web app and resource

I test my connection, that is successful

Then I deploy successfully. But when I log into my azure portal and go to the App URL I am redirected to a tutorial

"Your App Service app has been created

Go to your app's Quick Start guide in the Azure portal to get started or read our deployment documentation"

Can someone point me in the right direction please,

Regards

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I deploy successfully. But when I log into my azure portal and go to the App URL I am redirected to a tutorial
>
> "Your App Service app has been created

The page you seen is `hostingstart.html` that is under your ***site\wwwroot*** folder, and you can find it if you access to your site file system via [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).

[image]

***hostingstart.html file under wwwroot folder:***

[image]

You can add **default document** for your web app that is displayed at the root URL for a website under **Application settings** blade in the Azure Portal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try redeploying the app with "Remove additional files at destination" option checked in Settings > File publish options of Publish window (Visual Studio).
Alternatively, you can also try to remove unnecessary default documents from Application Settings (Azure portal)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting all the files, stopping the server, starting it again and then republish did the trick for me.

That were some hours badly spent... :/

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers above I was able to get round my problem.

First thing I did was rename my opening page to Index.aspx

Then deleted / Recreated my Azure app, once I re deployed onto my Azure app, everything was working fine.

thank you again for the help above.